# is this php for loop correct?

Tags: php, for-loop

I am trying to run the pagerank script that I found on http://www.getrank.org/pagerank-script/. But I get an error message when I try it. Error message below.

is this a legit php code?

```
...
function _strord($string){
for($i=0;$i $result[$i] = ord($string{$i});
return $result;
}
...
```

I get this error on the line where the for statement starts.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ';' in /home/Desktop/test/pagerank-checker.php on line 73
```

Thanks.

Comment: it's not even remotely correct.

Comment: Since when you stopped believing the interpreter?

Comment: Go [here](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

Comment: we don't need the full script - the link you posted is sufficient to see what happened here...

Comment: thanks guys. yes, I think it should have at least two ; in the for loop. @Alnitak I posted full script just in case someone wants to fix it.

Comment: @Thupten just do "view source" on that web site you copied - the answer should be obvious!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the **source code** of what's written on that page you'll see:

```
function _strord($string){<br>
   for($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++)<br>
       $result[$i] = ord($string{$i});<br>
   return $result;<br>
}<br>
```

The code has not been properly escaped, so the browser treats the text starting `<strlen` as the start of an HTML tag, and misses out some vital code...

Without the mark up it reads:

```
function _strord($string){
   for($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++)
       $result[$i] = ord($string{$i});
   return $result;
}
```

---

**EDIT** a cleaner implementation is this:

```
function _strord($string) {
    return array_map('ord', str_split($string, 1));
}
```

Comment: thank you. You spotted it right. I should have realized. Thats a good lesson. Always check the source code if the webpage contains source code in html.

Answer (score 3):

You need a comparison and an increment:

```
function _strord( $string) {
    $result = array();
    for( $i = 0, $len = strlen( $string); $i < $len; $result[$i] = ord($string[$i]), $i++);
    return $result;
}
```

I've also optimized it to omit the call to `strlen()` repeatedly within the loop.

Answer (score 1):

No idea what are you trying to get there, but the function should look something like this:

```
function _strord ($string ) {

  for( $i=0; $i<strlen( $string ); $i++ ) {
    $result[$i] = ord( $string[$i] );
  }

  return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function _strord($string){
    $result = "";
    for($i=0;$i < strlen($string), $i++)
        $result[$i] = ord($string[$i]);
    return $result;
}
```